# Can't display model of review of product in html in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am using python 2.7 and django 1.8.

I have created a model for product reviews with rating in my e-commerce site. My model is correct but I can't understand how to make function in views.py and how to create template for that in html.

I have added my function of views.py but i don't know what to write in the template.

**models.py(not all shown)**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)

objects = ProductManager()

class Meta:
    ordering = ["-title"]

    def __unicode__(self): #def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def get_image_url(self):
        img = self.productimage_set.first()
        if img:
            return img.image.url
        return img #None

    def average_rating(self):
        all_rating = map(lambda x: x.rating, self.review_set.all())
        return np.mean(all_rating)

class Review(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2,'2'),
        (3,'3'),
        (4,'4'),
        (5,'5'),
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)
```

**My views.py(not all shown)**

```
class ProductListView(FilterMixin, ListView):
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    filter_class = ProductFilter


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["now"] = timezone.now()
        context["query"] = self.request.GET.get("q") #None
        context["filter_form"] = ProductFilterForm(data=self.request.GET or None)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            qs = self.model.objects.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query) |
                Q(description__icontains=query)
                )
            try:
                qs2 = self.model.objects.filter(
                    Q(price=query)
                )
                qs = (qs | qs2).distinct()
            except:
                pass
        return qs


def review_list(request):
    latest_review_list = Review.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:9]
    context = {'latest_review_list':latest_review_list}
    return render(request, 'products/review_list.html', context)

def review_detail(request, review_id):
    review = get_object_or_404(Review, pk=review_id)
    return render(request, 'products/review_detail.html', {'review': review})
```

Answer (score 1):

So, in your context you're generating a list of `Review` objects as `latest_review_list`, so in your template you'll access it by `{{ latest_review_list }}` and you can iterate through it like:

```
{% for review in latest_review_list %}
    {{ review.field_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

then your `review_detail` view you're using `review` as the context data, so you'll just access it with `{{ review }}`.

I'm not sure what your plan is with `ProductListView`, but you can add a `template_name` property to that like:

```
class ProductListView(FilterMixin, ListView):
    template_name = '/my_templates/product-list.html'
```

And you'll access the object in this view using `{{ object }}` unless you override the `context_object_name` property on the view:

```
class ProductListView(FilterMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
```

Then you could access the list like `{{ product_list }}` in the template.